# How to run java directly from terminal

Tags: java, terminal, interpreter

In python; i can use this to start python interactive interpreter:-

```
$ python3
>>>...
```

But i am unable to start java interpreter directly in terminal without using java file and then compiling it. Is there a way to do it or we have just to use java file and then opt that traditional way of using `javac` and `file.java` commands?

Comment: you could try https://ideone.com/

Comment: Install Java 9: http://www.baeldung.com/java-9-repl

Comment: Install java9, then run `jshell`

Comment: Why not answer or at least up the answer you gave as a comment?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that worked; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Java JDK 9 you can use the Jshell tool to do that:
[Jshell Introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8)

Comment: great tool. Well; can we use all functionality of java by that?

Comment: Not sure what you encompass within "all functionality of java", but you should be able to run pretty much everything you code within, fairly sure there are way to compile and run a jshell with a classpath as well so you can use libraries etc..